# Hive: passing parameters

Tags: hive, hiveql

@libjack:

Hi,

I wanted to pass parameters into the hql from ksh script.
I went through Apache hive using variables document. The below worked fine where I set the values inside hql:

```
SET hivevar:parm1=valu1;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${parm1};
```

But I wanted to pass the parameters while invoking hive inside ksh. I have the variables and its value in a file as below:

```
--hiveconf:
SET hivevar:parm1=valu1;

--Inside .ksh:
hive --hivevar "'cat ${hiveconf}`" -f hiveScript.hql

--hiveScript.hql:
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${parm1};
```

This fails. I tried with hiveconf as well. 
How to pass the variable to hql?
Is it possible to pass as a file?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464636/how-to-set-variables-in-hive-scripts

Comment: I got this working, but the hiveconf and hivevar does not take file name.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39309609/2700344